# Closing WPF hosted in Outlook

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto

I'm making outlook vsto addin that launches WPF window.
It works fine, but when I close the WPF window, and try to open another one, I get a

> Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

exception.

I know that Application class is singleton, I understand exception, but I don't know how to close application when window is closed. I tried setting `ShutdownMode` in App.xaml and `App.Shutdown()` on window close, but without success. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="OutlookAddIn3.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OutlookAddIn3"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static App myapp;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void EnsureApplicationResources()
    {
        if (App.myapp == null)
        {
            myapp = new App();
        }                                
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //App.Current.Shutdown();
        App.myapp.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Ribbon1.cs

```
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        App.EnsureApplicationResources();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `myapp` field to `null` in order for a new `App` object to be created the next time you call `EnsureApplicationResources()`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    App.myapp = null;
    App.EnsureApplicationResources();
}
```